# Tensorflow Estimator shuffle

Tags: tensorflow

From [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators) link

The `tf.data.Dataset.shuffle` method uses a fixed-size buffer to shuffle the items as they pass through. In this case the `buffer_size` is greater than the number of examples in the Dataset, ensuring that the data is completely shuffled (The Iris data set only contains 150 examples).

Is shuffle method created in addition to feature engineering when I would shuffle and split my dataset to create training data? What is the advantage of: `"to shuffle the items as they pass through".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shuffle is a generally useful method if you want to shuffle your data and you didnt have an option to be able to do it before, like when you are reading from a generators for example. The shuffle method is also really useful if you want to shuffle your data each time you iterate through it (typically in combination with the [repeat](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat) method). Here is a quick example that shows why:

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).shuffle(5).repeat(3).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).shuffle(5, reshuffle_each_iteration=False).repeat(3).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

sess = tf.Session()

for i in range(15):
    d1, d2 = sess.run([dataset1, dataset2])
    print("Dataset1: {}, Dataset2:, {}".format(d1, d2))
```

Result:

```
Dataset1: 0, Dataset2:, 3
Dataset1: 3, Dataset2:, 0
Dataset1: 4, Dataset2:, 1
Dataset1: 1, Dataset2:, 2
Dataset1: 2, Dataset2:, 4
Dataset1: 1, Dataset2:, 3
Dataset1: 2, Dataset2:, 0
Dataset1: 3, Dataset2:, 1
Dataset1: 4, Dataset2:, 2
Dataset1: 0, Dataset2:, 4
Dataset1: 3, Dataset2:, 3
Dataset1: 0, Dataset2:, 0
Dataset1: 4, Dataset2:, 1
Dataset1: 1, Dataset2:, 2
Dataset1: 2, Dataset2:, 4
```

As you can see, the second dataset is repeating the elements it shuffled once, while the first dataset shuffles the data each time it iterates through the dataset.